# How to keep ssh-tunnel alive for accessing db using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, ssh-tunnel

I'm currently SSH'ing into a db and using sequelize in node. Everything works fine when I start the server. However after a few hours, the SSH tunnel stops responding and I get a sequelize connection error, see below.

```
SequelizeConnectionError: (conn=-1, no: 45012, SQLState: 08S01) Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1000ms
```

Here's how I'm SSH'ing into the server. This is models index file for sequelize.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const dbconfig = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};
const { createTunnel } = require("tunnel-ssh");

const os = require("os");
let sequelize;

const sshOptions = {
  host: "xyz.com",
  port: 22,
  username: "username",
  privateKey: require("fs").readFileSync("./id_rsa"),
};

async function mySimpleTunnel(sshOptions, port, autoClose = false) {
  let forwardOptions = {
    srcAddr: "localhost",
    srcPort: port,
    dstAddr: "localhost",
    dstPort: port,
  };

  let tunnelOptions = {
    autoClose: autoClose,
  };

  let serverOptions = {
    port: port,
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    createTunnel(tunnelOptions, serverOptions, sshOptions, forwardOptions)
      .then(() => {
        if (dbconfig.use_env_variable) {
          sequelize = new Sequelize(
            process.env[dbconfig.use_env_variable],
            dbconfig
          );
        } else {
          sequelize = new Sequelize(
            dbconfig.database,
            dbconfig.username,
            dbconfig.password,
            dbconfig
          );
        }

        fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
          .filter((file) => {
            return (
              file.indexOf(".") !== 0 &&
              file !== basename &&
              file.slice(-3) === ".js"
            );
          })
          .forEach((file) => {
            const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
              sequelize,
              Sequelize.DataTypes
            );
            db[model.name] = model;
          });

        resolve(sequelize); // Resolve the promise with the sequelize instance
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}

async function initialize() {
  try {
    await mySimpleTunnel(sshOptions, 3306).then((sequelize) => {
      db.sequelize = sequelize;
      db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    });

    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
    return db; // Return the db object
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error initializing sequelize:", err);
    process.exit(1); // Exit the process if initialization fails
  }
}

module.exports = {initialize};
```

Here's an example of a model:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {initialize} = require("../../models");

initialize().then(async (db) => {
  router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const checklist = await db.Checklist.findOne({
        where: { valuation_id: id },
        raw: true,
      });
      res.send(checklist);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to come up with a middleware to run in server.js to listen for a connection timeout but I was unsuccessful in coming up with something robust. Any ideas how to keep the connection alive or restart it if timeouts?